# Flutter - Alterar internacionalização de nomes de datas

Tags: dart, flutter

Sou novo em Flutter e gostaria de saber se é possível traduzir automaticamente os nomes dos dias da semana, mêses, etc ... englobando todo aplicativo?

Comment: Sim, é possível. O que você tentou até agora? Algum código?

Comment: Já tentei utilizar: intl: ^0.15.8 e em void main() { Intl.defaultLocale = 'pt_BR'; initializeDateFormatting("pt_BR", null); }, mais recebo uma excessão: Locale data has not been initilized

Answer (score 15, accepted):

É possível sim.

No `pubspec.yaml` adicione o `flutter_localizations` como:

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

Então no seu `MaterialApp` inicial defina os delegates e as linguagens suportadas:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

//...
MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
  ],
  supportedLocales: [const Locale('pt', 'BR')],
);
```

Agora um exemplo de código completo utilizando um DatePicker do próprio SDK:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      supportedLocales: [const Locale('pt', 'BR')],
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyApp> {
  String _value = '';

  Future _selectDate() async {
    DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2019),
        lastDate: DateTime(2020));
    if (picked != null) setState(() => _value = picked.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Exemplo localização'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(_value),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: _selectDate,
                child: Text('CLIQUE'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Antes de adicionar a localização ptBr:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora após, note que as Strings foram traduzidas/localizadas para o ptBr, não apenas o mês como os botões também.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para utilização de internacionalização mais complexa, recomendo ler na [documentação](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization).

Comment: Vlw Julio, Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) para utilizar o [DateFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) desta forma você consegue formatar as datas referentes as localidade que você deseja.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
   sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
   sdk: flutter

  intl: ^0.16.0
```

Para utilizar basta importar o pacote

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

E utilizar a classe DateFormat, por exemplo:

```
DateFormat(DateFormat.YEAR_MONTH_DAY, 'pt_Br').format(DateTime.now());
```

Ficaria assim a saída: Sexta-feira, 17 de janeiro de 2020