# Como alterar o idioma do plugin Image Picker do Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, image, câmera

Eu gostaria de alterar o idioma do texto que é apresentado na biblioteca [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker), eu gostaria de deixar este texto traduzido para o idioma do celular do usuário.
Se a imagem de como é apresentado hoje ao abrir a câmera: [image: Tela atual ao abrir a câmera, apresenta dois botões onde apresentam respectivamente o palavra "Retake" e "Use Photo"]

Eu gostaria de alterar o texto "Retake" para "Tirar Novamente" caso o idioma do dispositivo for português.

A função para a abertura de câmera está assim:

```dart
File file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
```

**Este problema acontece somente no iOS**

Comment: Depende se a lib suporta, mas por acaso você já tentou localizar o seu app para ptBr? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/399390/flutter-alterar-internacionaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-nomes-de-datas/399415#399415

Comment: Já realizer a configuração das localizationsDelegates e das supportedLocales que a minha aplicação suporta, que no caso é inglês, português e espanhol, mas nem precisaria seguir o idioma da aplicação, só de usar o idioma do dispositivo já ficaria contente, porque melhoraria a experiência do usuário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os passos para se resolver a seguinte questão se encontra aqui: [Spanish support for Retake and Use photo buttons of UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588857/spanish-support-for-retake-and-use-photo-buttons-of-uiimagepickercontroller)

Onde o desenvolvedor deve adicionar na configuração do projeto do iOS os idiomas suportados pela aplicação!

No meu caso  o erro foi que eu estava colocando somente inglês como idioma da aplicação. [image: Tela de adição de localização de projetos iOS]
Ao adicionar mais idiomas a abertura de câmera mudou a linguagem utilizada nas palavras como demonstrado nas imagens a seguir, deixando-as no idioma do dispositivo:

[image: Alterado o idioma das palavras abaixo.]

Comment: Testei isto e funcionou. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

O plugin não tem essa funcionalidade, você pode sugerir aos desenvolvedores [aqui](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new) ou você pode clonar o projeto e implementar você mesmo ajudando a comunidade.